# Using jQuery input event to conditionally update a <td> innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to do something that at least for me is complicated.

I have this in a much larger table:

```
 <table><tr>
 <td class="editC" id="comments:942" onchange="TimeLine();" onclick="empty('comments:942');" title="Click to edit..."> Second test of new comment behavior 
 </td></tr></table>
```

Here is what is going on:
1) class="editC" = I use Editable to edit and write to the DB.
2) id="comments:942" = the id value
3) onchange="TimeLine();" = The timeLine() function gets information from another DB and puts it into a second HTML table on screen. This works.. no worries.
4) onclick="empty('comments:942')" = empty is a function to empty the field but it does not update the DB. I just want a clean input field to enter new data in place of the existing data.

What I'd like to happen is this.

a) If something is typed into this now empty field, all is good, my save.php code will save it to the DB. This works great.
b) But if nothing is typed into the now empty field, I want the old value put back in place without updating the DB. In my head this would be equivalent to first having cut the current value then pasting it back if nothing new had been typed.

It seems to me that jQuery should be able to do this with the input event.

```
 function empty(thisID){
    $(thisID).on('input',function(){
       $(this).val()   // should get current value
    });
   document.getElementById(thisID).innerHTML = ''; // empty the field

   ... but now what? How do I determine if a change was made? How do I replace the original value if a change wasn't made?
 }
```

But now what? How do I determine if a change was made? How do I replace the original value if a change wasn't made?

Comment: What?? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: td elements do not have a change event.

Comment: Forget the onchange event, it is not important here. Pretend I didn't type it please.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser just a question, when you say *I use Editable* - well, how you mean exactly? the TD is Editable? ...what's *editable* exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`td` elements do not have an `input` event. It is however possible to nest an `<input>` tag inside a `td`.

```
$("td input").on("focusin", function() {
    currentValue = $(this).prop("value");
    $(this).prop("value", "");
}).on("focusout", function() {
    if($(this).prop("value") === "") {
        $(this).prop("value", currentValue);
    }
});
```

Here, when the input is clicked, found using the `focusin` event, the value of the input is stored in a global variable. It needs to be global, because we have to use this variable in the next function. After the variable is stored, the input field is erased, by setting the `value` attribute to an empty string.

If the user didn't make any changes and leaves the input field, detected with the `focusout` event, the `value` attribute will be reset to what it once was.

Current Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a592awoo/1/

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you are passing in `'comments:942'` to your `empty` function.

So when you do `$(thisID)` it is trying to find an element `<comments:942>`. To select by an id you need a `#`.

You could do this:

```
$('#'+thisID)
```

Or simply pass in `'#comments:942'`.

However, that won't work either. Using a `:` in an id is typically a bad idea, as it has a special meaning in CSS and jQuery selectors, so you may want to use a `-` instead. If that's not an option, you can [escape the `:`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/).

Even with the jQuery selector fixed, I'm not sure how you are trying to get user input on a `<td>` element. You need an `<input>` element.

I believe you are trying to accomplish something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this will add a click function to all elements with a class of 'editC'
  $('.editC').on('click', function() {
    //clear the current value
    $(this).empty();
    //append an input element
    $(this).append($('<input type="text" placeholder="Enter new value">'));
    //append a button
    var btn = $('<button>Submit</button>');
    //add click function on submit button to replace old td value with what is in the input
    $(btn).on('click', function() {
      //get the parent <td> element
      var td = $(this).parent();
      //get the previous element's value (the value of the <input> element)
      var val = $(this).prev().val();
      //remove the input element and button from the td
      $(td).empty();
      //set the text of the <td> to what was entered in the input element
      $(td).text(val);
    });
    $(this).append(btn);
    //unbind the click event, so that it does not perform this function when you click in the input element
    $(this).unbind('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='editC' id='comments-1'>Value 1</td>
    <td class='editC' id='comments-2'>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```